# I suspect my system is locking up occasionally because it's overheating. Any suggestions to diagnose an overheating issue?

Tags: cooling, diagnostic

For about a year now, I've been trying to diagnose occasional system freezes/lockups--no BSOD, no warning or messages after reboot--the system simply freezes. I reboot/reset and everything works fine.

I've done lots of things: memory (RAM) check, hdd scan, installed a new network driver, and even exchanged a SATA cable to the hdd. I've had it cleaned of dust with compressed air twice this past year. The computer is in an open area and near a window in fact.

I've ran out of ideas on how to proceed; but recently, this came to mind: that perhaps the case is too small. The case right now has two 18 cm fans but no fan on top or in front (because there's no openings in the front or on top).

My question to you: How do you go about diagnosing overheating? What component is overheating and locking up windows? I've been using Everest to monitor the temperatures. After a lockup and upon rebooting, Everest usually gives me these temps: 52 C mobo, 50 C cpu and 31 C on the Seagate. What I'm after, I suppose, is a diagnostic tool that can tell a novice like me whether these temps are too high for the parts I have. Then, I'm guessing the case should probably be replaced.

By the way, are there tools that can check my voltage readings to the cpu/mobo? Attaching output here.

[image]

specs: AMD Phenom II (quad), chieftec ps (500W), gigabyte mobo, radeon hd 4600 series, windows XP.

Comment: why not to set a kind of powersaving policy in power preferences?. I don't know if your system can hang at CPU being 120C' hot, but sure that you don't like the noise of coolers trying to cool down 50'C normal CPU (Phenom II X6 stable running at 40' here).

Comment: Yes, the fans are rather loud, now that you mention it. Louder than similar builds at work & friends' I recall.  By "hang" do you mean "freeze" or "stay"?

Comment: When you say you did a memory check, did you run a continuous test over an extended period like a weekend or at least overnight? Have you tried a mains filter?

Comment: Yes, memtest at least 24 hours; and no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50' is nowhere near hot enough to cause a Phenom CPU to become unstable.  However, if the temperature is normally 50' or higher in your system, it would seem to indicate that your case is not cooled as well as it could be.  It shouldn't be enough heat to lock up your listed components, but you may get less of a lifespan out of them.  You definitely wouldn't go wrong with a case and fan upgrade.  If you do, be sure to check your PSU to make sure that it will provide sufficient power if you upgrade the case and fans.

I would also walk through all of your system components' drivers and make sure you have the latest updates for all of them.  I know you mentioned the network driver, but any installed component can potentially cause a system freeze.

You might also get someone who's had some experience with it to dig through the system log and see if there's anything being caught just before each freeze that could point to a culprit.